# AngularJSもしくはJavascriptでPopup windowを表示したい。

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJSで
`$window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet', 'ツイートする');`
でPopup window(新しいWindow)を開いてツイートしたいのですが、新しいタブが開いてしまいます。
`window.open()`でも同様です。

Popup windowを新しく生成するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet','windowName','width=465,height=465')
```

とします。ng-click経由で呼び出さない場合、[スパム扱いでポップアップブロックされる](http://lazesoftware.com/blog/14/0106/)ので注意してください。
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/59naga/52y2vzw5/)

> [window.open - Web API インターフェイス | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/window.open)

なぜ`$window`を使うのかというと、[Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html)でテストを書く時、`window`を使っちゃうと、[テストが書けないから](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window)、だそうですね。実際には`window`と同じAPIが提供されます。

Comment: できました！ありがとうございます。
サイズ指定が必要なんですね